# Implicit conversion with type constraints using "where" to exclude(or include) types

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, implicit-conversion

(Question at the bottom)

I have a class which I need to be used like:

```
float [] floatArray=new float[1024];

Foo<float> var1=floatArray; // creates foo, assigns the array to a field

var1.compute();
```

and

```
Foo<float> floatArray2 = new Foo<float>(1024);

Foo<float> var2=floatArray2; // creates foo, copies its internal array 

var2.compute();
```

Then I thought I could use two implicit conversions, one for arrays, one for non-arrays.

I could manage to do first version with:

```
    public static implicit operator Foo<T> (T[] b)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(uint) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(byte) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(char) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(double) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(long) ||
            typeof(T) == typeof(float))
        {
            Foo<T> foo = new Foo<T>();
            foo.arr = b;

            return foo;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

but this has a lot of checks in it and I tried to add constraint in class declaration like:

```
   public class Foo<T> where T:typeof(float),typeof(int)
   {
      ...
   }
```

but it made the compiler complain as "int is not a valid constraint".

In the second case, I needed to exclude arrays, I tried this:

```
    public static implicit operator Foo<T> (Foo<T>  b)
    {         
            Foo<T> foo = new Foo<T>();
            foo.arr = b.arr;

            return foo;
    }
```

but this time compiler says "cant take enclosing type and convert to enclosing type" and underlines `operator Foo<T>`.

But these actually work:

```
    public static implicit operator Foo<T> (Foo<float>  b)
    public static implicit operator Foo<float> (Foo<T>  b)
```

and I don't want to cross-convert `int` type to `float` nor `float` to `int`. Just `T` to same `T`(not all T to all T).

**Question:** How to constrain the implicit conversion to only arrays of primitive numbers like float,byte,double,long,int and 1-2 custom classes without adding too many typechecks in the method body(custom classes are generic with float int byte...)? (where keyword doesn't work on method `<T>` definition)

---

Foo already implements IList but IList could be anything like a `Bar[]` right? So I can't use interface to narrow the search I assume. Also I don't want the `=` to do a reference assignment for `Foo`, but create a new one(or just use the current, would be better) and copy its internal array, just like a struct, but still have many advantages of a class(inheritance, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic constraints on `C#` are somewhat limited, you can restrict `T` to be a `class` or a `struct`, but you can't restrict it to be only one of the speficied types like, `int`, `float`, `double`. So in order to solve this issue you are gonna either need to have a manual `if` check like you did or you need to add overloaded implicit operators for each type. Although it requires more work I would recommend overloading solution because it's more type safe.

On the second issue, adding an implicit conversion from a type to the same type itself is not allowed. The relevant part from the specification explains it in detail (C# Spec 5.0 *10.10.3. Conversion Operators*):

> For a given source type S and target type T, if S or T are nullable types, let S0 and T0 refer to their underlying types, otherwise S0 and T0 are equal to S and T respectively. A class or struct is permitted to declare a conversion from a source type S to a target type T only if all of the following are true:
>
> - S0 and T0 are different types.
> - Either S0 or T0 is the class or struct type in which the operator    declaration takes place.
> - Neither S0 nor T0 is an interface-type.
> - Excluding user-defined conversions, a conversion does not exist from    S to T or from T to S.
>
> For the purposes of these rules, any type parameters associated with S
>   or T are considered to be unique types that have no inheritance
>   relationship with other types, and any constraints on those type
>   parameters are ignored. In the example
>
> ```
> class C<T> {...}
> class D<T>: C<T>
> {
>   public static implicit operator C<int>(D<T> value) {...}        // Ok
>   public static implicit operator C<string>(D<T> value) {...} // Ok
>   public static implicit operator C<T>(D<T> value) {...}      // Error
> }
> ```
>
> the first two operator declarations are permitted because, for the
>   purposes of §10.9.3, T and int and string respectively are considered
>   unique types with no relationship. However, the third operator is an
>   error because C is the base class of D.

Note: When you need to manually check the type of a generic parameter it usually indicates a design flaw in ur code, so you should think again about making the `Foo` generic. Does it really have to be generic? I'm assuming this is not the only place where you check the typeof `T`, you are probably gonna need to check the type again where you actually use the array of `T` and manually cast the items to that type in order to operate with them.

Comment: It has to be generic to act as an array and a custom class at the same time to hide many details from client developer. Trying to make it look like an array with many functionalities hidden(gpgpu) and be usable in pure C# codes(implicit array extraction from field) and have number types or custom class number types as an inner array.

Answer (score 1):

You can have limit `T` to `struct` this will let you already quite good compile time support.
Then, create a private constructor and make all the type checking there, including the assignment of the array.
There is no way that i know of to change the reference assignment of the same type, so that requirement cannot be met.

```
public void GenericImplicitTest()
{
    int[] ints = new int[4];
    char[] chars = new char[5];
    Foo<int> foo = ints;
    Foo<char> foo_s = chars;
    // Foo<float> f = ints;  <-- will not compile

}

class Foo<T> where T: struct 
{
    private readonly T[] arr;

    private Foo(T[] arr)
    {
        if (typeof (T) != typeof (int) && typeof (T) != typeof (uint) && typeof (T) != typeof (byte) && typeof (T) != typeof (char) &&
            typeof (T) != typeof (double) && typeof (T) != typeof (long) && typeof (T) != typeof (float))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{typeof (T)} is not supported");

        this.arr = arr;
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo<T>(T[] b)
    {
        Foo<T> foo = new Foo<T>(b);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to set the array via the constructor then create a private static `Create` method;

Comment: Do you mean using `not equal && not equal &&`  is more concrete and quicker in runtime than `equal || equal || ..` ? Should I benchmark a lookup table for this? Would it be optimized away to same performance? I mean saving some different `T` as an array of booleans to be used in a dictionary. Maybe JIT makes same thing in behind?

Comment: No, its just a habit of mine to return or throw as early as possible. So there's no need for else block here.